# Why doesn't Vaadin show logo image after deployment?

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin14

I have a Vaadin 14 App with Spring Boot. Locally I see the image, but after deploying it as a fat jar, the logo won't appear on the deployed app. I can't find any hint why its not visible.
Does anyone have an idea?

Here the implementation:

```
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver, RouterLayout, PageConfigurator {

    LoginForm login = new LoginForm();

    public LoginView() {
       //Other stuff

    Image image = new Image("images/logo.png", "logo");
    add(image);
  }
}
```

And the image is here:
/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/images/logo.png

The App only shows an empty image, when I do a *right click > open image* in new tab I see this Error in browser:

```
Could not navigate to 'images/logo.png' 
Reason: Couldn't find route for 'images/logo.png'
```

Comment: Did you build with `mvn clean package -Pproduction`?

Comment: Also you can see what is inside the uber jar with your favourite Zip Tool. At root level you should be able to find `META-INF/resources/images/logo.png`

Comment: @Avec yes Jenkins Build it with clean package -Pproduction. The Präfix „mvn“ is added by Jenkins

Comment: The image is packed in the .jar file

Comment: Image is in the exact correct path? 
So if you run the application with `java -jar application.jar` and access the application the image is not displaying? So if you open developer tools inside the browser and inspect the "non displaying image" what is the path shown to you?

Comment: yes, thats the way i start thr app. In developer mode it shows src="images/logo.png"

Comment: Ok. If I inspect the logo I have the same `<img src="images/logo.png">`. If I hover over the the source value `images/logo.png` the full url is shown as `http://localhost:8080/images/logo.png`. This stuff works out of the box so I guess you might have changed something. Did it work in the beginning before you did some changes to your code?

Comment: yes it woked some days before. The only changes i made was updateing spring to spring-boot-starter-parent
        <version>2.6.2</version>

and Vaadin to version 14.5.1

Comment: i updated to vaadin 14.8.0 and removed jenkins' workspace. now the logo is back :)

Comment: Good you managed to fix it.